# How to upload Image File to GoogleDrive In Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-api-dotnet-client

I Wondered If there is any way to upload image from application to Google Drive in Xamarin forms , I followed Google Drive API using this link

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

but in xamarin this way doesn't work some libraries is not available

This is my code

```
 var image = new Image

            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile(filepath)
            };

            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = "photo.jpg"
            };
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath,
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = DriveService.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

DriveService show me compiling error and i don't know if this way will work or not , Any help ?

Comment: The google api .net client library does not [support Xamarin](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/984)

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT still not

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive API is available in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.So you can use `DependencyService` and upload the image in iOS and Android platform.

> in Forms ,creat the Interface

```
public interface IUploadFile
{
  void UploadFile(string filePath,string fileName);
}
```

> iOS Implementation

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UploadFileImplementation))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{

  public class UploadFileImplementation : IUploadFile
  {
    public UploadFileImplementation () { }

    public UploadFile(string filePath,string fileName)
    {
        // upload file here

    }
  }
}
```

> Android Implementation

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UploadFileImplementation))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{

  public class UploadFileImplementation : IUploadFile
  {
    public UploadFileImplementation () { }

    public UploadFile(string filePath,string fileName)
    {
        // upload file here

    }
  }
}
```

You can download  Google Drive API  for [iOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.iOS/) and [Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.Android/) from nuget.And it provide [sample](https://cloudrail.com/integrations/services/GoogleDrive;interfaceId=CloudStorage;interfaceFunctionId=CloudStorage-upload) how to upload file on native platform.